# Fast C/C++/MATLAB SURF Feature Library

Tags: c++, matlab, computer-vision, surf, matlab-cvst

What is the fastest C/C++ implementation of SURF out there? Is OpenCV superior or are there any standalone implementations that are faster? Matlab Mex wrappers is a plus.

Comment: OpenCV 2.3.x also includes GPU (CUDA) version of SURF which is up to 12 times faster than CPU version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that one of the GPU-based solutions listed in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SURF#Implementations will be faster than the OpenCV version on the CPU. Of course, your mileage may vary depending on the specific application.